# １次元配列を木構造の形に成形したい

Tags: アルゴリズム, データ構造

自身のIDと親IDを持つOriginalDataを木構造の形にしたいと考えています。

`inputDatas`を`result`の形に変換したい

再帰的な処理をしたいのですが、いい方法が思いつきません。

言語は特に何でも大丈夫です。

```swift
struct OriginalData {
  let id: String
  let parentID: String?
}

struct Node {
  let id: String
  var children: [Node]
}

let inputDatas: [OriginalData] = [
  .init(id: "1", parentID: nil),
  .init(id: "2", parentID: "1"),
  .init(id: "3", parentID: "2"),
  .init(id: "4", parentID: "1"),
  .init(id: "5", parentID: "4"),
]

let result = Node(id: "1", children: [
  Node(id: "2", children: [Node(id: "3", children: [])]),
  Node(id: "4", children: [Node(id: "5", children: [])])
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

入力データが表す構造が木になっていることを仮定すると、深さ優先探索のようなことをすれば計算できます。

1. 入力は child から parent が探せる形になっているので parent から child たちを探しやすいように parent id を key、child id たちの配列が value になるような辞書にする。（これをしなくても計算はできるので、やらなくてもよい。）
2. 木の根（parent が nil な node）から見て `Node` の構築を始める。
3. 今見ている node について `Node(id: "ほにゃらら", children: ???)` までは作れるので、`children` を以下のように作る。

   - ひもづく child たちがいなければ自分が木の葉（末端 node）になる。つまり `children` は `[]`。
   - ひもづく child たちがいれば、それぞれに対して手順 3 を行って返ってきた node たちを `children` にする。

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまく実装できました。

Answer (score 0):

```swift
extension Node {
  mutating func addChild(allData: [OriginalData]) {
    for i in children.indices {
      children[i].children = allData.filter { children[i].id == $0.parentID }.map { .init(id: $0.id, children: [])}
      
      for j in children.indices {
        children[j].addChild(allData: allData)
      }
    }
  }
}
```